# Simple-to-use "if field exists" logic?

Tags: apex, trigger, developer

Is there simple to use logic that equals "**if a field exists, then...**":

```
if( **fieldname__c exists** ) then { ... }
```

..?  I really don't want to have to worry about a ton of class or other logic.  I'm hopeful someone has a clue what to replace the if clause with, because I have no idea.

This is to come up with a much more simplistic fix for a problem I've been trying to resolve via two other questions.  :-/

## 1:  [After Delete - Need To "Cleanup" When An Opp Is Deleted](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10593/after-delete-need-to-cleanup-when-an-opp-is-deleted)

## 2:  [Apex TRY ... CATCH ... FINALLY Syntax](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10600/apex-try-catch-finally-syntax)

Having this would give me the solution I need (but more specifically that I want without having a ton of code or yet another Trigger).

Added Note:  My fallback IS GOING to be the TRY-CATCH logic.  I'm just hopeful there is something more elegant / appropriate.

Comment: E.J. Wilburn covered this amazingly well in an answer to a similar question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/1056/60

In short, describes are conceptually cleaner but notably worse in real-world situations. Try/catch with dynamic apex is "ugly" but efficient.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use the Describe methods.  In the example below, replace `My_Object__c` with the name of the pertinent sObject.

```
Set<String> objectFields = Schema.SObjectType.My_Object__c.fields.getMap().keySet();
if(objectFields.contains(fieldName)) {
  //do stuff
}
```

Note, don't repeatedly call `Schema.SObjectType.My_Object__c.fields.getMap()` as there are governor limits around describe calls.  Call it once and save the list.

Comment: Thanks for the insight (and to @ca_peterson for the link as well).  When I get back to working on this, I am going to implement what I've learned here, and already have ideas on keeping the code relatively small based on how the fields are named.    Thanks again!

Comment: Limits for all Apex describe calls have been removed in [Summer '14](https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Summer14/New+Apex+Enhancements)

Comment: Please note here that objectFields will contain all fields in lowercase. So in `contains() ` method, you need to do `fieldName.toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Utility method you can use for checking any Object for any fields

```
public static Set<String> Util_checkFldsExist(Sobject sobj, Set<String> fldsToChk){
    Set<String> fldsThatExst = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> allObjFlds = sobj.getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet();
    for(String currFldName : fldsToChk){
        if(allObjFlds.contains(currFldName.toLowerCase())){
            fldsThatExst.add(currFldName);
        }
    }
    return fldsThatExst; //returns field names in lowercase
}
```