# Update delete event in same trigger

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger

Please let me know the reason for record captures for delete operation failing here.

Code:

```
trigger AccountHistoryTracker on Account (after update,after delete) {
    List<Schema.FieldSetMember> trackedFields = SObjectType.Account.FieldSets.HistoryTracking.getFields();

    if (trackedFields.isEmpty()) return;

    List<AccountHistoryTracking__c> fieldChanges = new List<AccountHistoryTracking__c>();

    List<string> apiNameList = new List<string>();        

   // if(Trigger.isUpdate|trigger.isdelete){

        for (Account aNew : trigger.isDelete ? trigger.Old : trigger.new) 
        {
            Account aOld = trigger.oldmap.get(aNew.Id);

            for (Schema.FieldSetMember fsm : trackedFields) 
            {
                String fieldName  = fsm.getFieldPath();
                String fieldLabel = fsm.getLabel();

                if (aNew.get(fieldName) != aOld.get(fieldName)) 
                {
                    String oldValue = String.valueOf(aOld.get(fieldName));
                    String newValue = String.valueOf(aNew.get(fieldName));

                    AccountHistoryTracking__c aht = new AccountHistoryTracking__c();
                    aht.name         = fieldLabel;
                    aht.apiName__c   = fieldName;
                    aht.User__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
                    aht.OldValue__c  = oldValue;
                    aht.NewValue__c  = newValue;
                    aht.createddate__c = system.now();
                    aht.Account__c = aNew.Id;

                    apiNameList.add(aht.apiName__c);
                    fieldChanges.add(aht);
                }        
            }
        }
    //}

    try{
        if (!fieldChanges.isEmpty()) {
            insert fieldChanges;
        }
    }catch(DMLException e){
        System.debug(e.getMessage());    
    }
}
```

Comment: which is line 16? Its most likely that aOld.get(fieldName) or aNew.get(fieldName) is returning null.

Comment: Sorry Prady! here is the faulty line. for (Account aNew : trigger.new)

Comment: Delete trigger cannot have a trigger.new. It would use only trigger.old

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete trigger cannot have a trigger.new. It would use only trigger.old. You would need to separate the logic for update and delete or use something like this

```
for(Opportunity opp : trigger.isDelete ? trigger.Old : trigger.new){
```

as used by techtrekker in his answer to this question [After Delete - Need To "Cleanup" When An Opp Is Deleted](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10593/after-delete-need-to-cleanup-when-an-opp-is-deleted)

Comment: Hi Prady still it fails to capture changes. Edited the question to give you the whole code. Please let me know my fault.

Comment: What is the error you are getting